# How to query a specific resource through the Jenkins API?

Tags: xml, xpath, jenkins, jenkins-cli

I'm trying to learn how to use Jenkins API in the most efficient way.

Assuming this is my server (a Jenkins master)
https://mf4.xiph.org/jenkins/computer/api/xml

I'm trying to find the most efficient way to retrieve the value of the ***offline*** key for the computer whose ***displayName*** is ***thomas-armv7***  (these are real values from the link above).

Assuming I have dozens of computers in this host, I want to get one only since it provides better performance to retrieve it this way (I believe).
I tried some URI combinations but couldn't find the right one yet.

Answer (score 2):

Use XPath:

```
/computerSet/computer[displayName='thomas-armv7']/offline
```

And add an `xpath` query parameter to the Jenkins API XML with the above value, such as:

https://mf4.xiph.org/jenkins/computer/api/xml?xpath=computerSet/computer[displayName=%27thomas-armv7%27]/offline

Comment: Thanks, it works! I'm trying to accept that but the system stops me.

Comment: This solution builds the complete list of computers (nodes) and filters the result. This is not as efficient as querying only the computer that OP is interested in.

Comment: Agree. +1 to your answer

Answer (score 1):

If you know the name of the node that you want to query, then it's more efficient to use the API to retrieve just that node:

https://mf4.xiph.org/jenkins/computer/thomas-armv7/api/xml?xpath=slaveComputer/offline

If you want to examine the results of multiple nodes or filter based on a parameter other than the node name, then you'll need to use a variation of [Stéphane Bruckert's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39214136/172599).